# Android log java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android

I'm getting an exception I don't understand. From device 350, only three such. Below is the log itself:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3724)
     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4261)
     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17356)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3719)
      ... 11 more
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
     at com.ex.MainActivity.ParseQueryMap(MainActivity.java:397)
     at com.ex.MainActivity.onClickParse(MainActivity.java:493)
     ... 14 more
```

Here is where I think the mistake is coming from:

```
public void onClickParse(View view) {        
  myMap.clear();
  ParseQueryMap();
}
```

And the query from the database (ParseQueryMap)

```
public void ParseQueryMap() {
  userLocation = new ParseGeoPoint(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
  ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("MyObject");
  query.findInBackground(new FindCallback() {
    public void done(List<ParseObject> myObject, ParseException e) {
      if (e == null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < myObject.size(); i++) {
          commGet = myObject.get(i).getString("Comment");
          bugGet = myObject.get(i).getObjectId();
          geo1Dub = myObject.get(i).getParseGeoPoint("location").getLatitude();
          geo2Dub = myObject.get(i).getParseGeoPoint("location").getLongitude();
        }
      } else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
    }
  });
```

Does anyone know what's causing this error?

Comment: Which line is line 397? There's a reference there that is `null`.

Comment: +1 to Santa's comment because we can help you much better if we see which line is #397 as listed in stack trace.

Comment: What do you mean by "From device 350, only three such"?

Comment: @Santa --- 397 line is public void ParseQueryMap() { userLocation = new ParseGeoPoint(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

Comment: @Justin Morgan --- this log was sent to me from Google Play that out of 350 installations, these errors were 3 devices

Comment: how are you initializing location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually this happens when an object reference is null in a place where your code assumes it will not be null.  One of the easiest ways to find it:  Set a debug breakpoint at line 397 in your IDE, run the app in debug mode, then use inspect/watch on each name or expression in that line to find out what has a value of null.